# Is there a way to use a resource file in the other assembly?

Tags: wpf, localization, globalization

I am using WPFLocalizeExtension library.

Until now, I have used the library as below.

```
xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com" 

<Button Content="{lex:Loc key=Yes}"/>
```

Of course, the code above works well, if "Yes" word is in the current assembly.

But this case, I would like to use the resource of the external assembly so I tried as below.

```
xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com" 
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="ApplicationLayer.Define"

<Button Content="{lex:Loc key=Cancel}"/>
```

But the code above does not work.

Maybe I think, it's because the reference assembly doesn't exist in the current directory.

The path of the file above is the "...\Applications\WpfApp\WpfApp" and the path of the "ApplicationLayer.Define" (The file to reference) file is the "...\Applications\ApplicationLayer.Define".

The resource file to use is in the Properties folder of the "ApplicationLayer.Define" as below.

[image]

---

update

Also, I referenced "ApplicationLayer.Define" assembly into the running application as below.

[image]

What I should do to achieve my goal?

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Reference the compiled `ApplicationLayer.Define.dll` assembly from your running application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already referenced ApplicationLayer.Define assembly to the running application. I updated my question.

Comment: Then you need to look into what the WPFLocalizeExtension library that you are using actually does. I am afraid I wouldn't know.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason that doesn't work.

The above resource file name is "Resource.resx". (see the image file)
I changed the resource file name to the "Resources.resx".

And then all works well.

Maybe I think, It's because the WpfLocalizeExtension library finds the "Resources.resx" name for resource to use.

Thanks for your interest.